# PHP form empty validation not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have created my form and most of my validation seems to work except my last 3 if statements for q1-3. I have tried a number of different ways but if I leave the form empty it fails to come up with the last 3 error messages set.

If anyone could notice what I am doing wrong or have any ideas?

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
  $errorMessage = "";

  if(empty($_POST['UserName'])) 
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a UserName!</li>";
  }
  if(empty($_POST['Password'])) 
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a Password!</li>";
  }
   if(empty($_POST['Password2'])) 
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to confirm your Password!</li>";
  }
   if(empty($_POST['FirstName'])) 
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a First Name!</li>";
  }
   if(empty($_POST['LastName'])) 
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a Last Name!</li>";
  }
   if(empty($_POST['Gender'])) 
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to select a Gender!</li>";
  }
   if(empty($_POST['DOB'])) 
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your DOB!</li>";
  }
  if(empty($_POST['Email'])) 
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your Email!</li>";
  }
   if(empty($_POST['q1'])) 
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to answer question 1!</li>";
  }
  if(empty($_POST['q2'])) 
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to answer question 2!</li>";
  }
  if(empty($_POST['q3'])) 
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to answer question 3!</li>";
  }
  //if they are not then set them to this
   $UserName = $_POST['UserName']; 
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];
    $Password2 = $_POST['Password2'];
    $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
    $Gender = $_POST['Gender'];
    $DOB = $_POST['DOB'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Q1 = $_POST['q1'];
    $Q2 = $_POST['q2'];
    $Q3 = $_POST['q3'];



  if(!empty($errorMessage)) 
  {
    echo("There was an error with your form:\n");
    echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
  } 
 else{ 
 $result=mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `users` (UserName, Password, Password2, FirstName, LastName, Gender, DOB, Email, q1, q2, q3) 
    VALUES ('$UserName', '$Password', '$Password2', '$FirstName', '$LastName', '$Gender', '$DOB', '$Email', '$Q1', '$Q2', '$Q3') ")or die(mysqli_error($db));
     header('location:welcome-page.php');
    exit;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
  Username:<br>
  <input type="text" name="UserName">
  <br>
   <br>
  Password:<br>
  <input type="password" name="Password">
<br>
<br>
 Please Confirm Password:<br>
  <input type="password" name="Password2">
<br>
  <br>
 First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="FirstName">
<br>
  <br>
 Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="LastName">
<br>
  <br>
Gender:<br>
<select name="Gender" id="Gender">
    <option value="female">Female</option>
    <option value="male">Male</option>

  </select>
<br>
<br>
Date Of Birth:<br>
  <input type="text" name="DOB">
<br>
  <br>
Email:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Email">
<br>
  <br>
Why have you decided to use this application?:<br>
 <textarea name="q1" cols="50" rows="10" class="textarea">

</textarea>

<br>
  <br>
What three things would you like to get out of this application?:<br>
  <textarea name="q2" cols="50" rows="10" class="textarea">

</textarea>

<br>
  <br>
What time constraints do you foresee and how can you plan around them?:<br>
   <textarea name="q3" cols="50" rows="10" class="textarea">
   </textarea>
<br>
  <br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>

<li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="1110151" />


  </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
```

Comment: form code please?also your first if is not closed?

Comment: Please show your form HTML.

Comment: share html to check q1 type.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections with this code. Output the `$_POST['q1']`, `2`, and `3`, and see what is there.. Also try simplifying the code to just the 3 conditional still reproducible?

Comment: I have now added the HTML, im guessing because its a text area this may be the problem?@santosh-ram-kunjir SQL injection is not a problem at this stage @chris85

Comment: Your text areas aren't empty.

Comment: What spaces is not empty, http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php. Use `var_dump` and you will see the variables are populated. (Yea, SQL injection is your current issue but still should be fixed..)

Comment: Thanks @JonStirling. Silly error there!

Comment: @Jeigh , `if(trim($data) !== '')` will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know!

```
$UserName = $_POST['UserName']; 
$Password = $_POST['Password'];
$Password2 = $_POST['Password2'];
$FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
$LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
$Gender = $_POST['Gender'];
$DOB = $_POST['DOB'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Q1 = $_POST['q1'];
$Q2 = $_POST['q2'];
$Q3 = $_POST['q3'];

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $errorMessage = "";
    if(empty($_POST['UserName'])) {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a UserName!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['Password'])) {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a Password!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['Password2'])) {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to confirm your Password!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['FirstName'])) {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a First Name!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['LastName'])) {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a Last Name!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['Gender'])) {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to select a Gender!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['DOB'])) {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your DOB!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['Email'])) {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your Email!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['q1'])) {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to answer question 1!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['q2'])) {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to answer question 2!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['q3'])) {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to answer question 3!</li>";
    }
}

if(!empty($errorMessage)){
    echo("There was an error with your form:\n");
    echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
}else{
    $result=mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `users` (UserName, Password, Password2, FirstName, LastName, Gender, DOB, Email, q1, q2, q3) VALUES ('$UserName', '$Password', '$Password2', '$FirstName', '$LastName', '$Gender', '$DOB', '$Email', '$Q1', '$Q2', '$Q3') ") or die(mysqli_error($db));
    header('location:welcome-page.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I understand that, Well, what I've done is putting the declarations above the if statements to make sure it set up right. then I edited the if statement which it was wrong because the first if statement was not closed. Therefore,  when the submit button is clicked the other if statements should work! ./1337